# MQTT: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subjectAltNames on the certificate match

Tags: android, ssl, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to connect with server via paho client (version which I'm using is `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.1.jar`)

When I try to connect I'm getting:

> "MQTT: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subjectAltNames on the
>   certificate match"

But I didn't get this issue in `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar`

This below is the log from mosquitto

> "sslv3 alert certificate unknown"

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No @shantanu, Do you have any idea about this issue?

Comment: Did you find the solution ? @kavie

Answer (score 2):

That error has nothing to do with Paho or MQTT.

It means that the certificate presented by the broker doesn't match the host name used to connect to it.

You either need to get a new certificate for the broker that matches all the hostnames used to connect to it, or make sure you are using a hostname included in the SAN section of the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the replay,hostname is matching with broker,This issue is not there in paho client 1.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Though it's not a good practice, but if you trust your broker and don't want to verify it's identity, you can build a fake trust manager as below which verifies nothing (no ca certificate usage at client side) and client gets connected to broker without any exception (though communication remains encrypted).

```
private fun fakeSocketFactory() : SocketFactory {
    val trustManager = object: X509TrustManager {
        override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<out java.security.cert.X509Certificate>?, authType: String?) {}
        override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<out java.security.cert.X509Certificate>?, authType: String?) {}
        override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<java.security.cert.X509Certificate> = arrayOf()
    }
    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
    sslContext.init(null, arrayOf(trustManager), SecureRandom())
    return sslContext.socketFactory
}

override fun connect() {
    val options = MqttConnectOptions()
        ...
    options.socketFactory = fakeSocketFactory()
    client.connect(options,null,object:IMqttActionListener{
        ...
    })
}
```

It's similar to chrome's warning "Your connection is not private. " and our action "Proceed to (unsafe)".

Comment: I still get the following error : "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names present"

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time on this issue on my project, so even if it is an old issue, I will add some information, maybe it can help someone.

I had the same issue; my certificate (without `SAN` attribute) was working well with the mosquito client, and with my android app using `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar` but not with newer versions of this library.

I understood why it's works with `1.2.0`: there is an issue in this version, hostname is not verified (see [CVE-2019-11777](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-11777).

In `1.2.1` or upper, hostname is well verified, so you will have the issue `MQTT: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subjectAltNames on the certificate match`.

I don’t know why, but in android, hostname is verified only with `SAN` attributes, not with the `CN`. I’ts a custom android change in okhttp [OkHostnameVerifier.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/refs/heads/android11-release/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/tls/OkHostnameVerifier.java#120). **(EDIT: using `CN` for hostname verification is deprecated, see @hardillb comment. This is why Android no longer uses it.)**

For me there is 2 solutions:

1. Always add a `SAN` attribute that match the `CN` in your certificate (The best solution)
2. If you really need a certificate without `SAN` attribute: use a custom hostname verifier (with MqttConnectOptions#setSSLHostnameVerifier method) You can use the [OkHostnameVerifier.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/refs/heads/android11-release/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/tls/OkHostnameVerifier.java) with re addition the commented part:

```
  /**
   * Returns true if {@code certificate} matches {@code hostName}.
   */
  private boolean verifyHostName(String hostName, X509Certificate certificate) {
    hostName = hostName.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
    boolean hasDns = false;
    List<String> altNames = getSubjectAltNames(certificate, ALT_DNS_NAME);
    for (int i = 0, size = altNames.size(); i < size; i++) {
      hasDns = true;
      if (verifyHostName(hostName, altNames.get(i))) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    // BEGIN Android-removed: Ignore common name in hostname verification. http://b/70278814
    if (!hasDns) {
      X500Principal principal = certificate.getSubjectX500Principal();
      // RFC 2818 advises using the most specific name for matching.
      String cn = new DistinguishedNameParser(principal).findMostSpecific("cn");
      if (cn != null) {
        return verifyHostName(hostName, cn);
      }
    }
    // END Android-removed: Ignore common name in hostname verification. http://b/70278814
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Checking hostnames against the CN field has been depreciated since May 2000 (as part of RFC 2818 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818#section-3.1) more than 20 years ago